# ImageView cannot be cast to PhotoView

Tags: android, android-photoview

I am using the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library to display some images.

When I try to use PhotoView with Picasso, as shown in the [sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/PicassoSampleActivity.java) I get *ClassCastException* on this line:

```
PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);
```

This is what's shown in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PhotoView in your XML too, not ImageView. Do something like following:

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```